# Alternation row colors on ItemsControl by only applying a reusable Style

Tags: c#, wpf

It is a very common thing people do and I understand how it works. I just can't find a way to make it work by only the use of a **Style**.

Lets say I have this ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding stuffList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If I wanted to add an alternating row color I would do something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding stuffList}" AlternationCount="2">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" ... />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" TargetName="InnerGrid"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="InnerGrid"/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But I want to clear the xaml from this unwanted additionnal code. I will also need to re-use this mechanic. What do I do? I make a Style!

So, I want to apply a style to the ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding stuffList}" Style="{StaticResource AlternateStyle}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and let the magic happen in a stylesheep somewhere else like that:

```
<Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="AlternateStyle">
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

But it doesn't work.. I'm not able to find the correct Binding or TargetType for the Style (that would replace Grid here). I'm out of idea and can't find help where this is not handled in the xaml. I could use some help from experienced WPF programmers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Part of your problem is the Style.Resources. If you use snoop, you'll see that the style doesn't get applied to the grid at all. Unfortunately, when I fixed that by making the Grid style separate and applying it to the "InnerGrid", the bindings are still not causing the desired result.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35886/WPF-ItemsControl-with-alternating-items-and-hover....you won't be able to randomly apply alternating row colors with different container styles because the grid needs to be with the triggers so that you can use TargetName="InnerGrid".

Comment: I guess I'll need to use some code directly in the xaml then. Thanks.